# Infinite Loop While Trying to Sort, Breaking Ties Randomly in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a list of objects whose attributes include an integer. I'm trying to write a program that will sort them based on that integer (from high to low value), and if there are any ties, randomly shuffle the objects. (Think of it like breaking a tie by flipping a coin, but I want it to work even if there are three or more ties.)

Here's some example code I've written that replicates what I'm trying to do with a list of integers. (There's no actual difference between integers with the same value, of course, but in the actual program the objects have other attributes.)

```
import random as R
array = [25, 45, 10, 25, 15, 25]
sortedarray = sorted(array, reverse=True)
newarray = []
while len(sortedarray) > 1:
    if sortedarray[0] == sortedarray[1]:
        newarray.append(sortedarray.pop(0))
    else:
        challenge = sortedarray[0]
        samevalue = []
        while sortedarray[0] == challenge:
            samevalue.append(sortedarray.pop(0))
        while len(samevalue) > 0:
            sortedarray.append(samevalue.pop(R.randrange(len(samevalue))))
```

My thinking is: Sort the list, then check to see if the first and second values are equal. If not, that means there isn't a tie yet, so `pop()` the first value and `append()` it to `newarray`. If they are equal, that means there's a tie, so `pop()` all the items with that value into the list `samevalue`, and `pop()` those to `newarray` at random.

I'm running into an infinite loop, but I can't figure out why. I would definitely appreciate some insight, whether it be on why I'm looping or how I could do this more efficiently!

Comment: Something like `sorted(array, key=lambda x: (x.attribute, random.choice([0,1])))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about shuffling the list into a random order first using the `shuffle` method, then sorting it. That way the ties will be in a random order already.

Comment: Oh, didn't even know about that method. But cheers, this worked pretty well, and is easier on the eyes :). I'd still like to figure out why that third while loop never ended, but it won't haunt me til my dying day.